# How to count different values of field in dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, I have a direct query from an SQL Server. In the SQL Server, there is a column named `type` (which may have 5 different values) and a column named `count`. My goal is to count the sum of the `count` column for each value and divide them.

Suppose the values are:

| type | count |
| --- | --- |
| new | 20 |
| new | 10 |
| lost | 30 |
| total | 50 |
| total | 60 |
| decreasing | 10 |
| increasing | 5 |

I want to calculate :

```
sum(count when type = new)/sum(count when type = total)
```

I'm not familiar with DAX and I just know the simple codes. I do not know even it is possible or not. How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate this specifically, assuming there is a `type` column containing rows with values `new` and `total`, you can hard code this ratio by a measure on the form of:

```
New / Total := 
VAR _new = CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[count] ) , 'Table'[type] = "new" )
VAR _tot = CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[count] ) , 'Table'[type] = "total" )
RETURN
DIVIDE ( 
    _new , 
    _tot 
)
```